# installing a new SSD in laptop, optimal way to iso the old SSD to run as virtual MC when new drive installed

Tags: ssd, iso-image, migration

I got here from SO, could I hear thoughts on below.

I have had a search of the forums and can't find a direct hit for my query.

I am upgrading my 500gb SSD in my XPS13 to a 2tb Samsung imminently

I wish to make an image of the old laptop so that I can run it as a VM when the new SSD is installed.

> > Create an iso of the existing SSD and save it to an external hard drive (best to do this via virtual box?)

> > install new SSD and boot new version of windows from USB

> > save the old SSD image to the new SSD and run from virtual box.

any tips?

Answer (score -1):

Use disk2vhd, then you can use that image in hyper-v or convert it to any other container for vmware or virtualbox.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).